# Likewise, mount after login to domain

Tags: 12.04, mount, likewise

I installed Likewise on my Ubuntu machine(12.04).

I succeed to join the computer to the domain and make Ubuntu ask me for PAM and disable guest account.

What I couldn't figure out is how to make the users get their mapping drives from the server(or manually). I have tried some solutions like adding the mount command to the `/etc/fstab`, but because I added myself to the UBUNTU, the path is changing from users to users.

**The bottom line is**, that I am trying to write down a login script that will map the drives by Group ID(GID).

Can someone please send me a script template or suggest another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `pam_mount.so` to your `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` or `/etc/pam.d/gdm` or whatever display manager you use. Configure `pam_mount.so` in `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` with content for example:

```
<volume options="nobrl,file_mode=0600,user=%(USER),uid=%(USERUID),gid=%(USERGID)"
        fstype="cifs"
        server="servername"
        path="home$/%(USER)"
        mountpoint="/home/%(USER)">
        <sgrp>Student</sgrp>
</volume>
```

In my case it was a cifs remote filesystem, that is mounted if the user is in the group "Student".

To execute loginscripts I use `pam_exec.so` in the coresponding pam-file (`/etc/pam.d/*`), notice, they will be execute with root-priviledges.